# Does github support traceability?

Tags: git, github

In TFS developers create work items.  Checkins can be associated with a work item.  Then when all the work is completed some time later a developer can merge all the associated check-ins for a work item to the main trunk.  I think of this as "traceability" because the requirements (work items) are directly tied to the code in a query-able fashion.

This allows me to track the code that belongs to a feature.  Manually performing this task is error prone and difficult for non-trivial functionality.

Is traceability supported by github/git?  In other words, can I tie a commit to a requirement (whatever that may be in github/git) somehow?

Comment: I am considering [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/#!) if there is no native support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub implements this with [Issues](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/) and [Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Each work item can be planned as an Issue, with tags, assignees, etc. the way you would expect. When you commit code relevant to that Issue, referencing it in the commit message by the Issue number (eg `#123`) will link that commit on the Issue page. You can also [close the issue from the commit](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) with comments like `Fix #123` or `Closes #123`.

So that you don't have to reference the Issue in every commit (which is cumbersome, if not entirely forgettable), you can create a Pull Request for a long-running branch. The Pull Request stays up to date as you push changes to the branch, and you can reference the Issue from the Pull Request description in the same way (`#123`) to tie the two together. Pull Requests are GitHub's solution to code reviews, so they provide commenting and discussion tools before you merge the branch.

Comment: Is there anyway I can extra those mapped issues and commit logs and files lists? using any open source tool? @Krisjan

Comment: @Milson It's not clear to me what you want, but all I'd do is search Google for it anyway.

Comment: Is there any way I can extract the information from Github which shows the relationship between each issues with all commit logs associated with it into a separate file or log? @Kristjan